# Why my MySQL Workbench asking me password after every few interval and also during execution of complex sub-query?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

My MySQL Workbench is asking me for a password after after an interval and also during execution of complex sub-query.
It all started when I changed the maximum database read timeout from 60s to 600s because my sub-query taking more than 60 second to give result. Every time it reaches 60 second it gives a connection failed or timeout error.

[Mysql work bench asking password before showing result of each complex query or sub query execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAdEq.png)

I tried various trouble shooting but none works.